# How to store javascript objects in a database

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm a complete newbie to django/react and am trying to learn by creating a battleships game. I've written some of the frontend using React, but I want to store the game state, which I currently have as a javascript object, in my database through django so it can be shared by both players. My state object has two properties: an array array objects which represent the board state and history, and an array of Ship objects as shown below.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            history: [{ squares: Array(9).fill(null) }],
            ships: [new Ship(14, "N"), new Ship(37, "E"), new Ship(84, "S")]
        };
    }
//...
}
```

I'm thinking I might have to serialize the state object to do that, but not sure how to go about it. Most of the questions/answers I've seen talk about serialising a model, but I don't think that's what I need. I want to serialise a custom object, store it in the database, and then deserialize it when it is sent to the players' browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to store JSON objects with Django, like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

class Example(models.Model):
    example = JSONField(...)
```

Read more [here](https://www.laurencegellert.com/2018/09/django-tricks-for-processing-and-storing-json/).

However, in my experience, I've found it's easier to store the JSON as a string in the database, via a `TextField` or similar, and then parse the JSON when I need to. Here's some pseudocode:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
    json_example = models.TextField(...)
```

```
# where the model is used, perhaps views.py

import json
from .models import Example

def my_view(request):
    my_example = Example.objects.get(...)
    my_json = json.loads(my_example.json_example)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks wcarhart. My state will be utilised at the frontend, so I'm assuming I need to use something like JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse at the frontend, or am I missing something? Will these methods create and parse any JS objects, or do I need to customise somehow given that some of the properties of the state object are custom objects themselves?

Comment: @Richard Django comes with a templating language called [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/). Using the python `json` module, you can pass your JSON object to Jinja in a dictionary via the `render()` function. Then, in your template (which can be anything, HTML, CSS, JS, etc.), you can choose how to display the information

Comment: @Richard Here's an example from a recent project of mine: https://github.com/wcarhart/Soliloquy/blob/master/stage/views.py#L18. This is pretty standard for how Django passes information from model to view to template

Comment: @Richard if you see value in my answer, you can accept it with the green check mark next to it

Answer (score -1):

Convert the objects into JSON (Create an import/export function/method for the custom objects) and use an NoSQL (recommend it over SQL, in this case) database like MongoDB to store it.

Comment: You don't need a NoSQL database to store JSON and haven't for a long time now. There is both native JSON support in most databases now and you can also just store it as text.